# panic: runtime error: index out of range processing file

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a function that reads a collection of data from JSON file, but I keep receiving this error

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

and it's not importing all the data from json file,

I think there's something wrong in my for loop.

```
// read our opened xmlFile as a byte array.
byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

// initialize Int array
var interns Int

// initialize Com array
var companies Com

// unmarshal byteArray
json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &interns)
json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &companies)

// iterate through every student within our students array and
// print out the student ID, first & last name
for i := 0; i < len(interns.Int); i++ {
    fmt.Println("Student first name: " + interns.Int[i].Name.FirstName)
    fmt.Println("Student last name: " + interns.Int[i].Name.LastName)
    fmt.Println("Company name: " + companies.Com[i].CompanyName)
    fmt.Println("Company email address: " + companies.Com[i].CompanyEmail + "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using len of Int array to iterate Com array while len of Com array is different so the program will panic when iterate to an index that Com array is not available

```
//Program panics if [i] is not valid
fmt.Println("Company name: " + companies.Com[i].CompanyName)
fmt.Println("Company email address: " + companies.Com[i].CompanyEmail + "\n")
```

Split the loop into two to iterate and it will works

```
// iterate Int array
for i := 0; i < len(interns.Int); i++ {
    fmt.Println("Student first name: " + interns.Int[i].Name.FirstName)
    fmt.Println("Student last name: " + interns.Int[i].Name.LastName)
}
// iterate Com array
for i := 0; i < len(companies.Com); i++ {
    fmt.Println("Company name: " + companies.Com[i].CompanyName)
    fmt.Println("Company email address: " + companies.Com[i].CompanyEmail + "\n")
}
```